# Get the directory of a running file

Tags: vb.net, process

Would it be possible to retrieve the file directory of running files using `Process.GetProcesses()` method?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Dim processes As System.Diagnostics.Process()
processes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses
Dim process As System.Diagnostics.Process
For Each process In processes
    listProcess.Items.Add(process.ProcessName.ToString + " " + process.Id.ToString + " " + process.MainModule.FileName.ToString)
Next
```

However there may be "Access Denied" type errors because a lot of those processes will be running in protected directories like `C:\Windows\`

Comment: Hi @Makita! Thanks for replying so quick. I think this is the idea that I'm using right now as well. This is able to retrieve the directory of the running executable paths. I was thinking something like this: I open a notepad file from the Desktop. I want to retrieve the directory pointing to that notepad file, not the executable path of NOTEPAD.EXE. Is that possible?

Comment: I'd say basically not possible - you'd need each application to report the directory it is using at that time and very few applications would do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the command-line of each process that is running, and there's a chance that the path you're looking for was part of the argument, then you can parse that out of the result.

For example, notepad.exe will show the full path of it's open file as it's command-line parameter, so it might look like this:

`"C:\WINDOWS\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE" C:\Users\J.Scott\Desktop\testfile.php`

**The code:**

```
Dim cLineSearch As New ManagementObjectSearcher("root\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process")

For Each cLine As ManagementObject In cLineSearch.[Get]()

Try
    Debug.Print(cLine("CommandLine").ToString)
Catch ex As Exception
    ' Usually "Object not set to instance of an object" error
    'Debug.Print(ex.Message)
End Try

Next
```